# Should I get a PSX or PS2 for playing the classic WipeOut?

Tags: ps2, ps1, wipeout

I still have my original boxes and discs of WipeOut 2 and Wip3Out: Special Edition, and dying to play these games again (not the newer ones on PS3 or Vita).

Would it be better to buy a PlayStation 2 instead of a PS1? I'm guessing the games will be 100% compatible right?

How about the connection to an LCD screen? I have an [old BenQ FP93V](http://reviews.cnet.com/lcd-monitors/benq-fp93v/4505-3174_7-31645033.html) lying around with D-Sub and DVI connectors, is it easier to get adapters for the PS2 or the PSX?

Comment: Get an emulator instead. ePSXe is awesome.

Comment: Yeah I heard about it but there's no guarantee it's going to be 100% compatible, and it's just not going to be the same playing with the keyboard. In WipeOut the "shoulder buttons" were key to controlling the ship.

Comment: Well, it's certainly worth a try. I've played many PSX games with ePSXe and they run like a dream once you get the settings right. Picking up a controller should be less expensive than an entire console too.

Comment: Thanks, I'm worried about all the hassle of setting it up. Wip3Out uses multiple tracks on the CD so it seems a CUE file is required... been reading very complicated threads about how to "rip" my original PS1 games etc. >_>  ps: if not Sony's any PC controller you would recommend to use with ePSX?

Comment: If you have the disc you should probably be fine without ripping, ePSXe supports reading from an actual CD. It may or may not be legal to download a copy of a game you already own in your jurisdiction. Any DirectInput controller will do, I like Thrustmaster Dual Trigger (it's got great shoulder triggers, should be perfect for you). The time it takes to set up ePSXe will likely be less by several orders of magnitude than purchasing a PSX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Picking between PS1 and PS2 will ultimately come down to whatever it costs you to buy either, while the PS2 has some filters to make PS1 look smoother and load a bit faster, it won't make too much of a difference, in my opinion. PS1 Compatibility with PS2 is almost flawless, with the exception of some games. Looking over [this compatibility list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PlayStation_games_incompatible_with_PlayStation_2) it looks like you'd be OK with playing them on a PS2.
On either console, you'd need a PS1 memory cards to save game progress.

Connecting to a PC monitor is a separate issue. While converting component signal to VGA is possible through adapters (with varying results), you'd have to keep in mind only the PS2 supports component output, and [you may encounter some issues when trying to play PS1 games through it](http://www.digitpress.com/forum/showthread.php?159202-PS1-Games-in-component). You can try using converters from composite/s-video to VGA but this will look even worse on a PC monitor.

That leaves you with two other options. The cheaper one would be to emulate the game on a PC. You won't need a too powerful PC to emulate PS1, and the only hardware you might want to get is a DualShock-like PC controller or a PS1/PS2 DualShock and a USB adapter. I believe this will get you the best looking results.

A more expensive one is getting a PS3. It might be an overkill but if you don't have a PC capable of emulating it might be cheaper than upgrading to a new PC. All PS3 models work with most PS1 games ([although WipEout 3 does seem to have issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PlayStation_3_backward_compatible_PlayStation_2_and_PlayStation_games#W)), and they upscale them to run in resolutions suitable for monitors, but again you'll need a component to VGA adapter.

Comment: Thanks I think I had a [SCART adapter like this](http://www.obsessedgamers.eu/files/psx-psone_av_cable_with_scart_adapter.jpg) when connected to an old CRT television. Guess I could buy an old/small LCD television to hook it up to the PS2.